# Find top consecutive rows where a column value is equal between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get all the consecutive top row where a column value is equal between them

my table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
  [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
  [IdUser] [int] NOT NULL,
  [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [SomeData] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

and i want the top rows (ordered by `Id` desc) with the same `IdUser`

if table data is:

```
Id  IdUser  CreatedDate                 SomeData
--- ------- ------------------------    --------
1   1       2017-09-21T09:42:01.407Z    sdafsasfa
2   1       2017-09-21T09:42:01.407Z    sdafsasfa
4   2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.41Z     sdafsasfa
5   3       2017-09-21T09:42:01.41Z     sdafsasfa
7   3       2017-09-21T09:42:01.413Z    sdafsasfa
8   3       2017-09-21T09:42:01.413Z    sdafsasfa
9   10      2017-09-21T09:42:01.417Z    sdafsasfa
11  11      2017-09-21T09:42:01.417Z    sdafsasfa
12  2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.42Z     sdafsasfa
15  2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.42Z     sdafsasfa
```

I want :

```
Id  IdUser  CreatedDate                 SomeData
--- ------- ------------------------    --------
12  2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.42Z     sdafsasfa
15  2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.42Z     sdafsasfa
```

if table data is:

```
Id  IdUser  CreatedDate                 SomeData
--- ------- ------------------------    --------
1   1       2017-09-21T09:42:01.407Z    sdafsasfa
2   1       2017-09-21T09:42:01.407Z    sdafsasfa
4   2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.41Z     sdafsasfa
```

I want :

```
Id  IdUser  CreatedDate                 SomeData
--- ------- ------------------------    --------
4   2       2017-09-21T09:42:01.41Z     sdafsasfa
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e42df/52)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite [TriV's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342442/921690) works fine I ended up using a modified [Radim Bača's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46341148/921690) (his solution dont work as i need) because it is faster IMO

```
SELECT id, iduser, createddate, somedata
FROM Items t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM Items t2
         WHERE t2.id > t1.id and t2.iduser <> t1.iduser  );
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e42df/122)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query:

```
select I.* 
from 
[dbo].[Items] I 
JOIN
(select top 1 Id, IdUser from [dbo].[Items] order by Id desc)I2
on I.Iduser=I2.Iduser
order by Id desc;-- this can be removed to remove ordering by Id Desc
```

**[updated fiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e42df/4/0)**

Comment: i already tried this way but i get also a non consecutive rows (id 4 in your fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want last rows with highest CreateDate and same IdUser then  `DENSE_RANK` will help

```
SELECT id, iduser, CreatedDate, somedata
FROM (
    SELECT id, iduser, CreatedDate, somedata, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate desc, IdUser) ord
    FROM [dbo].[Items]) t
WHERE t.ord = 1
```

The equivalent SQL query is

```
SELECT *
FROM Items t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM Items t2
         WHERE t2.createddate > t1.createddate or 
              (t2.createddate = t1.createddate and t2.iduser < t1.iduser)
      )
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e42df/118)

Comment: this is quite what i'm looking for. did not know about DENSE_RANK(). But I need the reverse order

Comment: what exactly do you need in the reverse order? user ids?

Comment: @giammin I'm not quite sure what you need in the result when you have the same `CreateDate` and different `UserId`s

Comment: order by id desc.

Comment: @giammin I had a bug in the `DENSE_RANK` solution. I have added `desc` behind `CreatedDate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154981/discussion-between-radim-baca-and-giammin).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LAG` and `SUM() OVER()` like this

```
DECLARE @Items as Table 
(
  [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
  [IdUser] [int] NOT NULL,
  [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [SomeData] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Items
(
    Id,
    IdUser,
    CreatedDate,
    SomeData
)
VALUES

( 1 , 1 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 2 , 1 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 4 , 2 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 5 , 3 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 7 , 3 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 8 , 3 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 9 , 10,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 11, 11,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 12, 2 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa'),
( 15, 2 ,getdate(),'sdafsasfa')

;WITH temp AS 
(
    SELECT *,
         CASE 
            WHEN  lag(i.IdUser) over(ORDER BY i.Id) = i.IdUser THEN 0
            ELSE 1
         END as ChangingPoint          
    FROM @Items i
),
temp1 AS
(
    SELECT 
          *,
          sum(t.ChangingPoint) OVER(ORDER BY t.Id) as GroupId
    FROM temp t
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       t.Id,
       t.IdUser,
       t.CreatedDate,
       t.SomeData
FROM temp1 t
ORDER BY GroupId  DESC
```

See demo here: http://rextester.com/PHWWU96232

Answer (score 0):

```
select I.* 
from 
[dbo].[Items1] I 
JOIN
(select top 1 Id, IdUser,CreatedDate from [dbo].[Items1] order by Id desc)I2
on I.CreatedDate=I2.CreatedDate
order by Id desc;-- this can be removed to remove ordering by Id Desc
```

Comment: this return not consecutive rows